# How do I send commands to an EXE running through the command line with batch?

Tags: batch-file, command, cmd, pipe, exe

I have a server application running called TerrariaServer.exe and I want to be able to send it commands with separate batch file. TerrariaServer.exe is a program running as a command line. How could I "feed" it a command such as "save" and "exit"? The answer might be pipes, but I'm not too sure. Here is kinda what I executed in a batch file while TerrariaServer.exe was running...

```
@echo off
echo save | TerrariaServer.exe
echo exit | TerrariaServer.exe
```

After that, nothing happen. I don't know if you need to know this but this is a video game server and the "save/exit" commands come with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Eep, use type for multiline input!

```
echo save | TerrariaServer.exe
```

will open up TerrariaServer.exe and send "save" as input to it.

```
echo exit | TerrariaServer.exe
```

will open up TerrariaServer.exe and send "exit" as input to it.

See the problem yet? :P

You're executing TerrariaServer.exe **twice**!

You should use the command *type*. You can type a text document into the input of an executable. First, let's create this text document (or any file for that matter; the extension doesn't matter!)

```
echo save>somefile.txt
echo exit>somefile.txt
```

Now let's type this into TerrariaServer.exe...

```
type somefile.txt | TerrariaServer.exe
```

Maybe delete somefile.txt after we're done?

```
del somefile.txt
```

Hope that cleared things up! :)